# Has anyone managed to get Site-to-site VPN tunnel from Google Cloud VPN working with SonicWall?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Has anyone managed to get Site-to-site VPN tunnel from Google Cloud VPN working with SonicWall?

If so, can you provide the working configurations used on both sides?

We have tried to use IKEv2 and IKEv1 but cannot get the tunnel up. For IKEv2, we get a 'decryption failed' error and for IKEv1 we get a 'NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN' error.

Any help with a working configuration is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've been successfully using the following on the SonicWALL side:

**IKE (Phase 1) Proposal**
Exchange: IKEv2 Mode
DH Group: Group 14
Encryption: AES-256
Authentication: SHA1
Life Time (seconds): 36000

**Ipsec (Phase 2) Proposal**
Protocol: ESP
Encryption: AES-256
Authentication: SHA1
Enable Perfect Forward Secrecy (checked)
DH Group: Group 14
Life Time (seconds): 10800

I also have "Enable Keep Alive" and "Enable Windows Networking (NetBIOS) Broadcast" turned on.

On the GCP side, just plug in your IP settings, set to IKEv2, and enter your shared secret.

Answer (score 2):

The error message `NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN` is due to no match between the algorithms configured on the pair VPN gateways. For IKEv1 make sure that set of algorithms match completely. The list of supported values is documented on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns#setting_up_the_peer_vpn_gateway).

Answer (score 0):

Mismatch algorithms is the cause of that issue.
This is my site-to-site VPN Sonicwall to GCP VPN:

[Proposal Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/172nx.png)